# using environment variables in vuejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, environment-variables

I read this [articles](https://alligator.io/vuejs/working-with-environment-variables/) on how to use environment variables in vuejs.

I have setup my local .env.local file and installed dotenv

```
VUE_APP_AUTH_AUTHORITY = 'http://localhost/auth'
```

and I have a config file

```
export default {
  AUTH_AUTHORITY: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH_AUTHORITY,
}
```

This works on my local machine.

After preparing the build on the development, I want to deploy the build output to the production environment and set the environment variable in production.

The build has to be done in the development environment and the output sent to the production team at a different location.

At the it looks like the application is not picking up the env variable in production environment.

I have set the value for `VUE_APP_AUTH_AUTHORITY` on the server (windows 2012) and the application is running on IIS.

Does the value needs to be set during the build of the package for it to be available in the application?

Comment: Depending on the way you have your build setup, it might need to be set before the build of the package. Back when I was using gulp, it would bake in some of the env vars into the package so they had to be set before

Comment: is there a way to set it after the build? because I don't have access to the production environment.

Comment: You want to set the environment variables on the server on which the final app is actually being deployed, not the one creating the build. In order to actually help you we need more information about how you are deploying the app in production.

Comment: Yes, I want to set the environment variables on the production server and the build is done on the development environment.

Comment: I've added more information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify variables in `.env.*` you can not change it in runtime because these "variable names" just will be replaced with variable value during bundling with Webpack(it uses [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) for this).

You can see in output js bundle that your `process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH_AUTHORITY` **just replaced in code** with `'http://localhost/auth'` string. So env variables are used during build only(by Nodejs environment).

For production you should prepare `.env.production` with your variables and build your app with `production` mode.

See also docs: [Using Env Variables in Client-side Code / Vue Cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The only problem is that I don't have access to the production values. The value can be anything the production team picked and that value is not available to the dev team.

Comment: @capiono so the only way to provide values to create some runtime config, and change values manualy by guy who has access to prod values.